# How to search string on list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

Work on **C#**.I have a dataset I want to search string on this dataset table.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = ImportFromExcel(oOpenFileDialog.FileName, false);
...      
var w = (from p in ds.Tables["ReadExcel"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray()
         select p.ItemArray).ToList();

string[] sExcelString = {"Vessel Name :", "Voyage No. :", "Port :", "Terminal :",
```

"NMC Global File :" };

from this w list I want to search **sExcelString** string arrays all element .After search I want to get the list to retrive the related values.How to search on list and how to get the related list for next process.Bellow picture describe detail.

[image]

If have any query plz ask?Thanks in advance.

Comment: "`.ToArray().ToList()`" -- dear Lord, no

Comment: Yes, it will be same... if you call running in half the time "same"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **first** thing you want to do is re-write your "w" expression like this:

```
var w = from p in ds.Tables["ReadExcel"].AsEnumerable() select p.ItemArray;
```

.ToArray() and .ToList() should be saved as options of last resort — for example if you need to pass the expression to a function that requires an array or if you really want to protect the result against multiple iterations.  Calling them too soon forces an iteration of your data, and prevents you from using the nice composition properties of linq to narrow your result first (and thus save big on memory and execution time).

Once that is done, you can add additional "from" and "where" directives to join the data like so:

```
var w = from p in ds.Tables["ReadExcel"].AsEnumerable()
        where p.ItemArray.Intersect(sExcelString).Any()
        select p.ItemArray;
```

Note that I rarely use the query comprehension syntax; I prefer the function calls/lambda notation.  I also typed this right into the browser.  Put the two together and it's unlikely to work "as is".  The important thing here is that this should get you 90% of the way there.  Consider the last 10% a chance to really understand how this all works, so that you can better write future expressions.

Comment: Thanks for reply.especially for list and array part .thanks .your syntax show one error The name 's' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @shamim - I fat-fingered an extra "." in there. Fixed now.  Also, I added an additional disclaimer paragraph.

Comment: Now syntax works fine.But result of w show Enumeration yielded no results

Comment: var w = from p in ds.Tables["ReadExcel"].AsEnumerable() select p.ItemArray; syntax return a reslut ,but this w contain two list,first one as a parent second one is child .i need to search on child ,your syntax search on parent not on child ,so,run your syntax  i don't get any result.

Comment: @shamin - note the call to .Intersect()  that's where I descend into the child.  But I did spot a mistake.  Try again in a moment after I edit

Comment: Beyond this, there's also a type mismatch between your sExcelString[] and your ItemArray - the elements in one are typed as Object and the elements in the other are typed as Strings - if you also cast the objects as strings, you might have better luck.

Comment: result is Enumeration yielded no results

Comment: may be your are right ,string array and ItemArray elements are mis match ,Is there any way to use Regex

Answer (score 0):

After put the Excel value in dataset **ds.Tables["ReadExcel"]**string array **sExcelString3** values are retrieve respectively.Bellow syntax help to retrieve  string values.

```
         string[] sExcelString3 = { "Vessel Name :", "Voyage No. :", "Port :", "Terminal :", "NMC Global File :","Line : ","ETA : ","Total Container : " };
      //ItemArray);
  var w = (from p in ds.Tables["ReadExcel"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray() select p.ItemArray).ToList();

      foreach (string item in sExcelString2)
                {
                    var r3 = (from c in w
                             where c.Any(e => e.ToString().Contains(item))
                             select c).ToList();

                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(item);
                     foreach (var it in r3)
                     {
    //                     int r = it.ToList().FindIndex(p => regEx.IsMatch(p.ToString()));
    string result =r3[ it.ToList().FindIndex(p => regEx.IsMatch(p.ToString()))+1];
                     }




                }
```